# What is the partial derivative of the sum of the pairwise product of vector components

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

A function defined for $v \in \Re^{n}$ is

$f(v) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} v_iv_j$

which is basically the sum of the pairwise product of all components of $v$.

I'm trying to figure out the partial derivative $\frac{d}{dv_k}f(v)$.

What I'm thinking is, for any arbitrary $k$, $v_k$ occurs $n$ times as $v_i$, and $n$ times as $v_j$, with one occurance as $v_kv_k$. Then the derivative should be $\frac{d}{dv_k}f(v) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2v_i$.

But I'm not really confident about this argument.

---

And an extension of the question -

What will be the partial derivative of $g(v) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} v_iv_jv_k$, with respect to an arbitrary $v_s$.

I'm not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you can write $$f(v) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}v_{i}v_{j} = \bigg{(}\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}\bigg{)}\bigg{(}\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}\bigg{)}$$ and apply the product rule.

Comment: You mean product rule, but this is a good way to view it and generalizes well.

Comment: Yes, I mean the product rule. I edited it! :)

Comment: Yes that makes it easier to think about, thanks a lot! :)